# Need help with referencing using Biblatex APA style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style, author

So I have been struggling with Biblatex for a few days. I seem to get the hang of it for the most part but I'm still confused and stuck concerning a few details.

this is my header:

```
%Bibliography
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package not APA style
%\usepackage[sorting=none,style=apa]{biblatex} %APA style
\bibliography{sample} %Import the bibliography file
```

These are the first three references of my sample.bib:

```
@misc{Lindt1,
  author = {Ad Hoc},
  title = {Chocoladefabriken Lindt \& Sprüngli AG : Half Year            Results},
  year = {2021},
 
  %howpublished = "Available on \url{https://www.dgap.de/dgap/News/adhoc/lindt-spruengli-with-doubledigit-sales-growth-and-market-share-gains/?newsID=1466704,}",
  url ={https://www.dgap.de/dgap/News/adhoc/lindt-spruengli-with-doubledigit-sales-growth-and-market-share-gains/?newsID=1466704},
  note = {[Last visited: 17-12-2021]},
}

@misc{SOPP,
  author = {Europages},
  title = {SOPP INDUSTRIE GMBH - pack with love},
  year = {2021},
  note = {[Last visited: 18-12-2021]},
  % howpublished = "Available on \url{https://www.europages.co.uk/SOPP-INDUSTRIE-GMBH/00000005341101-001.html}",
   url ={https://www.europages.co.uk/SOPP-INDUSTRIE-GMBH/00000005341101-001.html}
}

@misc{STIR_In,
  author = {ST Integration \& Robotics},
  title = {Official company's Website},
  year = {2015},
  note = {[Last visited: 18-12-2021]},
  %howpublished = "Available on \url{https://www.st-ir.com/}",
   url ={https://www.st-ir.com/}
}
```

I was using the first line in the header and I thought howpublished looked better for me and that's why I added it.

This is how It looks with the first line. AKA:

```
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
```

[image: NoStyling]

Clearly the order of things is messed up as I wanted the APA style:Author, year, title, publication or link.

This is how it looks when I use the second line of the header and comment the first. Meaning:

```
%Bibliography
%\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package not APA style
\usepackage[sorting=none,style=apa]{biblatex} %APA style
\bibliography{sample} %Import the bibliography file
```

[image: APA]

It is the style I want but there are A few things that are just messed up:

1. Needed [last Visited on] to be the last thing in each line but couldn't
2. Author names are messed up. for example "ST Integration & Robotics" became what is shown in the picture. same with "Ad Hoc"
3. References in the whole document are no longer mentioned as [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfSyd.png),[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILtKY.png)... and are now the year of that citation ( 2015,2021 ...) and are no longer shown in the bibliography page as the previous one before each citation.

I am trying to fix these errors and get it to work, but my knowledge is fairly small and I really could apreciate a nudge to the right direction.

Thank you very much

Comment: What you're asking for isn't really APA style then. APA style is implemented pretty exactly with the `style=apa` option of `biblatex`. You should not add `sorting=none` since that's not how any author/year citation system works. And APA requires Author (Year) or (Author, Year) citation callouts not numbers. If you really want a mixed system, then you should not use the `apa` style at all. And posting code fragments makes it very hard for us to help you. It's better to post a tiny but complete compilable document that shows what you're doing.

Comment: using sorting=none with an author-year style isn't a good idea. How should a reader find the reference?

Comment: For corporate authors, you need to enclose the author in a further set of braces. See [Using a 'corporate author' in the "author" field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808). For numbered callouts with author year bibliography, see [Numbered In-text Citations With APA Style bibliography](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/618637).

Comment: My university requires APA style with [last visited] after the URL. that's all I was trying to do. The required layout is Author, year, URL, [last visited]. I was trying to sort the citation based on the order they appeared in the document. that's all.

Comment: If your university requires APA style (which I assume they are using generically to mean an author/year style), then you should use author/year callouts not numbers. If you need to reorder the elements in the bibliography you should work off of the basic `authoryear` style or the `ext-authoryear` style rather than the `apa` style itself.

Comment: if you want to sort by appearance then you should use a numeric style which allows the reader to find the reference. Without number sort by author alphabetically.

Comment: well The style they want is [#] increasing throughout the document and when you click on the reference you get directed to the specific reference with the corresponding information in the style I mentioned ( Author, year, URL, [last visited] )

Comment: If that's the style they want, it's *not* APA at all. But the second question I linked to in my previous comment should do most of what you want.  In that case you should get something working with that answer, and then change your question to ask about any further specific problem you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have already commented out, the style you are forced to employ has absolutely nothing to do with APA style.

If you have the chance to employ natbib/bibtex instead of biblatex/biber, I'd recommend that you do so, mainly because the `unsrtnat` bib style basically does all you need and want, including placing the contents of the `note` field ("[Last visited on ...]") at the very end.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{sample.bib}
@misc{Lindt1,
  author = {{Ad Hoc}},
  title = {{Chocoladefabriken Lindt \& Sprüngli AG}: Half Year Results},
  year = {2021},
  url ={https://www.dgap.de/dgap/News/adhoc/lindt-spruengli-with-doubledigit-sales-growth-and-market-share-gains/?newsID=1466704},
  note = {[Last visited: 17-12-2021]},
}
@misc{SOPP,
  author = {Europages},
  title = {{SOPP INDUSTRIE GMBH} --- pack with love},
  year = {2021},
  note = {[Last visited: 18-12-2021]},
   url ={https://www.europages.co.uk/SOPP-INDUSTRIE-GMBH/00000005341101-001.html}
}
@misc{STIR_In,
  author = {{ST Integration \& Robotics}},
  title = {Official company's Website},
  year = {2015},
  note = {[Last visited: 18-12-2021]},
   url ={https://www.st-ir.com/}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
%\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{sample.bib} % <-- use \addbibresource, not \bibliography

\usepackage{xurl} % allow arbitrary line breaks in URL strings
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cite{Lindt1,STIR_In,SOPP}

\bibliography{sample}
%\printbibliography
\end{document}
```